# Xcode 4.3 compile error of @try

Tags: xcode

when i upgrade my xcode from 4.2, the project could not build correctly as an error of @try in an .mm file.

the error message said it should not had a @ before try.

```
Unexpected '@' in program
```

Is the objective-c language changed or some other reason?

it's an objective-c file which import some header files.

exception_xxx.h

```
#define MY_EXCEPTION_TRY @try {
#define MY_EXCEPTION_HANDLE } @catch (NSException *localException) {}
```

and in some objective-c file(.mm file) , i import the exception_xxx.h

this code works perfect in 4.2 but fail in xcode 4.3.

Comment: Exception handling with `@try` blocks should be the same.  Is this an Objective-C file or C++?  (You mention that the file extension is .mm)

Comment: it's a head file, exactly.

exception_xxx.h

    #define MY_EXCEPTION @try

and the head file is imported by some objective-c files(which is .mm file)

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually being compiled as Obj-C?

Comment: yes,i think so.When i saw the type of the file is Objective-c++ source.

Comment: Same problem here with Apple LLVM 3.1. What to do? Is "@try" obsolete?

Answer (score 2):

Enabling C++ exceptions solved the problem for me.
But wtf Apple? Those are objc exceptions why do I need to enable C++ exceptions as well?

Answer (score 0):

also check complier flag see if there is something like

```
-fno-exceptions
```

This flag will overwrite "Enable C++ Exceptions" configuration in Xcode project settings